# using jquery function for mulitiple events and also no event statues

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I used these two functions for converting WooCommerce prices to persian format:

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){
      var els = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-Price-amount, .amount, .product-quantity');
      els.forEach(function(item) {
      item.textContent = persianJs(item.textContent).englishNumber().toString();
    });
});

jQuery(document).ready( function(){
      jQuery( 'body' )
      .on( 'init init_checkout updated_checkout checkout_error wc_cart_emptied update_checkout updated_wc_div adding_to_cart added_to_cart removed_from_cart ', function() {
      var els = document.querySelectorAll('.woocommerce-Price-amount, .amount, .product-quantity');
      els.forEach(function(item) {
      item.textContent = persianJs(item.textContent).englishNumber().toString();
      });
   });
});
```

First part (function) is for converting numbers to persian format in *Shop front page* and second part (function) is for *Cart* and *Checkout page* which are ajax event dependant.

Both functions are working well but I am not sure is there any solution to merge both functions?

Any advice and suggestions for improvement will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the contents of your top document ready is exactly the same as the contents of your secondary event handler.  So you should easily be able to extract that common logic out to a shared function.  Edit: And you do not need two document readies.  Just stick both the code blocks in the same one.

Comment: @Taplar If I don't use woocommerce javascript events (second part), this function won't work on checkout page.

Comment: I didn't say to not use the events.  https://imgur.com/8QwwzMS  I said those two blocks are the exact same logic, and can be extracted.

Comment: @Taplar So how to stick the part without event to the part with event?

Comment: *" So you should easily be able to extract that common logic out to a shared function."*